# Intercept specific exception module-wide in Python

Tags: python, exception

I have defined a custom exception I need to keep track of and trigger a process whenever it is thrown. Currently I enclose each line that is susceptible to raise that error in a `try`-`except` pair, but as the code grows, this starts to look more and more ugly and cumbersome.

Is there a way to make a module-wide `try`-`except` statement?

**tl;dr**

I am currently doing this:

```
class MyError(exception):
   pass 

try:
   #error-prone code
except MyError:
   context_aware_function()
```

And I am looking for this:

```
class MyError(exception):
   pass 

errorManager.redirect(from=MyError,to=context_aware_operation)
#error-prone code
```

Answer (score 2):

You could intercept exceptions on a per-function basis by annotating them with [decorators](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). A decorator is implemented as a function that takes a function as input and returns a modified version of the function. In this case we wrap the input function with a try/except block:

```
def catch_error(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kws):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kws)
        except MyError:
            #handle error
    return wrapper

@catch_error
def foo():
    #error-prone code
```

Comment: Good strategy. Combined with automated decoration of all functions this could be a good solution, but unfortunately my functions are hidden inside objects, so I really need a module-wide redirection.

Comment: You could use the python [introspection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) framework to iterate through the classes and functions in a module. Replacing each function with the wrapped version may prove tricky though...